# Checkbox unclick event Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have problem that checkbox uncheck event. When I unclick the checkbox it should be revert back. How can I do this?

```
<body>
<script>
 function change()
    {
        var cb = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0];
        var td = document.querySelectorAll("td[contenteditable]")[0];

        cb.addEventListener("click", function () {
            td.className = td.className + " crossed";
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the html for the checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either toggle the class like:

```
cb.addEventListener("click", function () {
   td.classList.toggle("crossed");
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/13mje283/)**
Or check if the `checkbox` is checked:

```
cb.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if(cb.checked) td.classList.add("crossed");
  else td.classList.remove("crossed");
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyfwzq8h/)**

If you want to keep the [older browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist), you can do it like:

```
   cb.addEventListener("click", function() {
     if (cb.checked) td.className += " crossed";
     else {
       var tdclass = td.className.split(" "),
         ind = tdclass.indexOf("crossed");
       tdclass.splice(ind, 1).join(" ");
       td.className = tdclass;
     }
   });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tkhxh5zd/)**

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd suggest a minor adjustment to the following:

```
function change() {
    // querySelector() returns the first element matching the
    // selector (or null, if no matching element is found):
    var cb = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]'),
        td = document.querySelector("td[contenteditable]");

    // use the change event on the check-box:
    cb.addEventListener("change", function () {

        // adds, or removes, the class 'crossed'
        // based on the assessment that follows;
        // of the cb node is checked (true) the
        // class is added (if not already present),
        // otherwise it's removed:
        td.classList.toggle('crossed', cb.checked);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

okay u want a tick to be re-enable when u click on it to unclick!!!

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").props('checked','false') {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").props('checked','true')
}
```

Try to use a selector like `id` or something in place of: `input[type='checkbox']`

Comment: While this may work, there is no indication that the OP is using jQuery. It shouldn't be assumed that this library can be added. At the very minimum it should be noted in your answer that this method requires the adding of an additional JavaScript library for the code to execute correctly...

Comment: Okay sir i wll take care of this next time